# NiFi(nifi) - How to get all runStatus of Process Groups of a Process Group

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]

Hello, I want to get all runStatus of processGroups of a Process Group, I could only search the way of getting the runStatus

`(localhost:8080/nifi-api/process-group/{id}/processors)`

but this way is only to get a runStatus (Not getting all runStatus of some process groups). Please let me know the way

Best Regards

Comment: Get the list of processors in group, then get the status for each

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with the [NiFi Python Client](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi) I maintain

```
import nipyapi
nipyapi.utils.set_endpoint('http://mynifihost:8080/nifi-api')
nipyapi.canvas.list_all_processors(nipyapi.canvas.get_process_group('MyPG').id)
```